# Get job status of fax send via Microsoft Fax Server (SBS2008)

Tags: vbscript, fax

Can someone provide my with a straightforward VBScript to check a fax job's status by referring to a known JobID? Handling a fax job event is not an option for me. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VBScript, but had to figure out how to do the same thing. Since you haven't gotten any answers, maybe this'll help somewhat.

I found this link to be the most helpful: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693402%28VS.85%29.aspx

In c#, the code looks like this:

```
FaxServer faxSrv;
faxSrv = new FaxServer();
faxSrv.Connect("");
FaxOutgoingMessage OneMessage = faxSrv.Folders.OutgoingArchive.GetMessage("201caa51861ed24");
Console.WriteLine("status of one message: " + OneMessage.DocumentName + " [] " + OneMessage.TransmissionEnd.ToString());
faxSrv.Disconnect();
```

The outgoing Archive only has successfully transmitted faxes.  For my purposes, if my fax is in that archive, I'm good.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Adam